# Change d3.js line graph stroke colour above a data point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to change the colour of the line if the data value is above a certain value?

Ive got the line graph working how I like, but I cant work out how to do the styling, any ideas?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xgebqe

```js
var m = [10, 10, 10, 10]; // margins
var w = 400; // width
var h = 200; // height
  
var data=[146.45,146.43,146.45,146.47,146.44,146.48,146.44,146.52,146.59,146.71,146.74,146.68,146.66,146.64,146.65,146.68,146.58,146.57,146.54,146.5,146.45,146.51,146.57,146.6,146.62,146.63,146.51,146.44,146.36,146.33,146.34,146.3,146.34,146.33,146.35,146.31,146.4,146.44,146.44,146.44,146.47,146.37,146.41,146.4,146.44,146.5,146.51,146.54,146.54,146.5,146.49,146.45,146.45,146.47,146.46,146.47,146.45,146.59,146.71,146.71,146.7,146.68,146.74,146.77,146.78,146.71,146.73,146.72,146.71,146.73,146.73,146.73,146.75,146.72,146.66,146.65,146.72,146.75,146.77,146.8,146.82,146.83,146.84,146.85,146.86,146.9,146.91,146.9,146.86,146.89,146.89,146.89,146.88,146.91,146.89,146.89,146.9,146.91,146.95,146.95,146.93,146.95,147,146.98,147,147.01,147.03,147.05,147.07,147.08,147.07,147.04,147.02,146.99,146.98,146.98,147,147,147.02,147.04,147.06,147.06,147.12,147.13,147.13,147.15,147.16,147.12,147.07,147.06,147.03,147.03,147.02,147.02,147.06,147.07,147.07,147,147,146.99,147,146.91,146.91,146.87,146.87,146.86,146.88,146.87,146.85,146.87,146.89,146.91,146.88,146.84,146.87,146.88,146.89,146.9,146.92,146.94,146.94,146.92,146.9,146.87,146.84,146.8,146.78,146.8,146.78,146.72,146.73,146.75,146.76,146.77,146.78,146.77,146.76,146.85,146.9,146.9,146.92,146.97,146.96,146.97,146.96,146.89,146.91,146.89,146.91,146.93,146.96,146.97,147.03,147.02,146.98,146.99,147,146.99,147,147,147,146.97,146.96,146.97,146.99,146.99,146.98,146.95,146.95,146.93,146.9,146.88,146.85,146.87,146.84,146.85,146.87,146.87,146.84,146.81,146.82,146.82,146.8,146.76,146.74,146.67,146.66,146.66,146.68,146.63,146.69,146.72,146.77,146.79,146.85,146.85,146.8,146.77,146.72,146.86,146.86,146.86,146.91,146.86,146.78,146.71,146.67,146.65,146.63,146.58,146.55,146.5,146.48,146.44,146.37,146.4,146.39,146.36,146.34,146.35,146.4,146.33,146.34,146.32,146.34,146.35,146.33,146.34,146.3,146.35,146.37,146.33,146.33,146.33,146.33,146.26,146.28,146.23,146.25,146.27,146.29,146.27,146.29,146.27,146.22,146.21,146.27,146.31,146.32,146.34,146.33,146.39,146.38,146.33,146.3,146.3,146.23,146.19,146.17,146.16,146.15,146.19,146.22,146.21,146.24,146.3,146.29,146.27,146.23,146.21,146.15,146.13,146.13,146.13,146.12,146.12,146.15,146.08,146.07,146.04,145.97,145.91,145.91,145.94,145.95,145.94,145.92,145.89,145.84,145.85,145.72,145.72,145.74,145.77,145.77,145.72,145.67,145.65,145.6,145.55,145.52,145.59,145.6,145.63,145.67,145.71,145.71,145.75,145.74,145.73,145.75,145.73,145.78,145.75,145.75,145.77,145.78,145.78,145.83,145.82,145.84,145.84,145.74,145.66,145.69,145.71,145.66,145.66,145.7,145.67,145.73,145.72,145.66,145.49,145.54,145.61,145.65,145.81,145.81,145.87,145.89,145.91,145.79,145.74,145.66,145.78,145.75,145.69,145.88,145.39];

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()

.x(function(d,i) { 
  return x(i); 
})
.y(function(d) { 
  return y(d); 
})

var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
.attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
```

```css
path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: url(#line-gradient);
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
<div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**, it's not possible. In a line chart like yours, the "line" is actually a `<path>` element, meaning that it has just only one stroke colour, only one stroke width, only one fill etc...

The classic SVG solution for your problem is using [clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking). I'm sure someone will shortly post an answer using that.

However, I'd like to propose a D3 based solution (or a data based solution if you want), although a not perfect one.

My solution is appending **two** different paths, filtering the data for each one. In your case, I'm filtering the data above and below `146.5` for each path:

```
graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data.map(function(d) {
    return d < 146.5 ? d : null
}))).attr("stroke", "blue");

graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data.map(function(d) {
    return d >= 146.5 ? d : null
}))).attr("stroke", "red");
```

For each path, I'm passing `null` values for values above (or below) the limit, and using a *line.defined* in the line generator.

Here is the demo:

```js
var m = [10, 10, 10, 10]; // margins
var w = 400; // width
var h = 200; // height
  
var data=[146.45,146.43,146.45,146.47,146.44,146.48,146.44,146.52,146.59,146.71,146.74,146.68,146.66,146.64,146.65,146.68,146.58,146.57,146.54,146.5,146.45,146.51,146.57,146.6,146.62,146.63,146.51,146.44,146.36,146.33,146.34,146.3,146.34,146.33,146.35,146.31,146.4,146.44,146.44,146.44,146.47,146.37,146.41,146.4,146.44,146.5,146.51,146.54,146.54,146.5,146.49,146.45,146.45,146.47,146.46,146.47,146.45,146.59,146.71,146.71,146.7,146.68,146.74,146.77,146.78,146.71,146.73,146.72,146.71,146.73,146.73,146.73,146.75,146.72,146.66,146.65,146.72,146.75,146.77,146.8,146.82,146.83,146.84,146.85,146.86,146.9,146.91,146.9,146.86,146.89,146.89,146.89,146.88,146.91,146.89,146.89,146.9,146.91,146.95,146.95,146.93,146.95,147,146.98,147,147.01,147.03,147.05,147.07,147.08,147.07,147.04,147.02,146.99,146.98,146.98,147,147,147.02,147.04,147.06,147.06,147.12,147.13,147.13,147.15,147.16,147.12,147.07,147.06,147.03,147.03,147.02,147.02,147.06,147.07,147.07,147,147,146.99,147,146.91,146.91,146.87,146.87,146.86,146.88,146.87,146.85,146.87,146.89,146.91,146.88,146.84,146.87,146.88,146.89,146.9,146.92,146.94,146.94,146.92,146.9,146.87,146.84,146.8,146.78,146.8,146.78,146.72,146.73,146.75,146.76,146.77,146.78,146.77,146.76,146.85,146.9,146.9,146.92,146.97,146.96,146.97,146.96,146.89,146.91,146.89,146.91,146.93,146.96,146.97,147.03,147.02,146.98,146.99,147,146.99,147,147,147,146.97,146.96,146.97,146.99,146.99,146.98,146.95,146.95,146.93,146.9,146.88,146.85,146.87,146.84,146.85,146.87,146.87,146.84,146.81,146.82,146.82,146.8,146.76,146.74,146.67,146.66,146.66,146.68,146.63,146.69,146.72,146.77,146.79,146.85,146.85,146.8,146.77,146.72,146.86,146.86,146.86,146.91,146.86,146.78,146.71,146.67,146.65,146.63,146.58,146.55,146.5,146.48,146.44,146.37,146.4,146.39,146.36,146.34,146.35,146.4,146.33,146.34,146.32,146.34,146.35,146.33,146.34,146.3,146.35,146.37,146.33,146.33,146.33,146.33,146.26,146.28,146.23,146.25,146.27,146.29,146.27,146.29,146.27,146.22,146.21,146.27,146.31,146.32,146.34,146.33,146.39,146.38,146.33,146.3,146.3,146.23,146.19,146.17,146.16,146.15,146.19,146.22,146.21,146.24,146.3,146.29,146.27,146.23,146.21,146.15,146.13,146.13,146.13,146.12,146.12,146.15,146.08,146.07,146.04,145.97,145.91,145.91,145.94,145.95,145.94,145.92,145.89,145.84,145.85,145.72,145.72,145.74,145.77,145.77,145.72,145.67,145.65,145.6,145.55,145.52,145.59,145.6,145.63,145.67,145.71,145.71,145.75,145.74,145.73,145.75,145.73,145.78,145.75,145.75,145.77,145.78,145.78,145.83,145.82,145.84,145.84,145.74,145.66,145.69,145.71,145.66,145.66,145.7,145.67,145.73,145.72,145.66,145.49,145.54,145.61,145.65,145.81,145.81,145.87,145.89,145.91,145.79,145.74,145.66,145.78,145.75,145.69,145.88,145.39];

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i) { 
  return x(i); 
})
.y(function(d) { 
  return y(d); 
})
.defined(function(d) { return d; })

var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
.attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data.map(function(d){ 
  return d<146.6 ? d : null}))).attr("stroke", "blue");

graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data.map(function(d){ 
  return d>=146.5 ? d : null}))).attr("stroke", "red");
```

```css
path { 
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: url(#line-gradient);
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;"></div>
```

This solution is not perfect because, as you can see, I had to introduce a hack for generating the blue line, otherwise you'll have a gap between the lines (which is the expected behaviour for *line.defined*).